# How to represent a list in model classes for an Entity Framework code-first application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

If I put a list of strings as a property in my model classes, how will it be represented in my database table?

If it is not possible to use list, what are the alternatives?

Let's say we are using the example class below:

```
class Product 
   {
    public productID {get; set;}
    public list<string> categories {get; set;}

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a `Category` type that would represent a category entity in the database (i.e. a `Categories` table). This `Category` type could have an `Id` and `Name` property.

I'm assuming the relationship between `Product` and `Category` would actually be many-to-many, therefore, your `Product` type would have a collection of `Category`, and your `Category` type would have a collection of `Product`.

In the database, Entity Framework would model this relationship using a junction table.